# Two targets with separate .xib (image resources with same names)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I have a project with two targets, let's say **appA** and **appB**.

Both targets **share code** of main view controller (appViewController) **except the .xib** files.

I also have **two sets of png's** each for one target.

My file/project structure looks like:

```
*common* (members of both targets):
    appViewController.h
    appViewController.m

*appA* (members of target appA):
    appViewController.xib
    set of png files

*appB* (members of target appB):
    appViewController.xib
    set of png files
```

PNG's in both sets have the same names but they are placed in separate folders/groups and one group is member of one target and the other of the other target (same with appViewController.xib)

**Everything works fine except when i try to edit .xib files in IB - it seemes to
get confused and show partly images from one target and partly from the other.**

Since .xib's are somewhat complex (>40 images) editing one with partly wrong images is
almost impossible - images have to be properly placed on one background image (background image is also different for appA and appB).

**The problem exists only at edit-time** (in IB). After compilation all the images in 
both targets are correct.

I found one quick & dirty solution to this. Before i start editing one .xib
i remove references to the other set of png's. That way IB shows correct images
for the .xib i'm editing. I simply import back all the references (png's of the other
target) when i'm done.

I found a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343860/xcode-4-multiple-targets-multiple-resources-folders-with-images-of-the-same-na) which was not really answered.

I wonder, does anyone have a cleaner solution to this? There has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: Open a ticket in the [Apple Bug Report](https://bugreport.apple.com) site.

Comment: Thanx! i'll probably really do that. Just wanted to check with the community if maybe i missed something in the documentation - i haven't read a lot on IB since i usually make all the GUI in code :)

Comment: bug reported under id 10736585

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No answers so far...

So let me answer my own question (still hoping for a better answer).

When you want to edit .xib of one target, you remove the references
of the other targets' resources (pngs).

Then you quit xcode and open your project again. The pngs will be
the right ones (since xcode doesn't hold references to the wrong ones
at the moment).

When you're done - reimport deleted references (take care that you
check the right 'target membership').

Edit: This seems to be a known issue with IB - XCode. Till they resolve it we'll just have to use workaround mentioned above.

Comment: After 8 years still the same issue in Xcode 11.7, unbelievable