# iOS full/lite version using multiple windows

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

I have two targets in my Xcode 4.3 project. Each target has its own X-info.plist file. I would like to have two windows (MainWindow.xib), one for the full app and one for the Lite version. I set the `Main Interface` for each target and also `Main nib file base name` in the X-info.plist but it's not working. What did I miss? 
Thx

Comment: I've posted a link below. If it doesn't answer your question please explain more about what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily have the even same names for .xib files for different targets. Just make sure that two files with the same name aren't members of the same target. They have to be placed in different directories on HD and in different groups in project.

There is also a known bug with IB (image resources and so on) and multiple targets: see more at [Two targets with separate .xib (image resources with same names)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878357/xcode-4-interface-builder-two-targets-with-seperate-xib-image-resources-with)

But this information is for XCode 4.2.x, not sure if it/s valid for XCode 4.3

Comment: Hum... I don't think I understand the first part. You say I can create two files with the same name (e.g. RootViewController.xib)? XCode doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: It should, i use it all the time. You have to keep them in separate directories on disk and separate groups in project. They also have to belong to different targets (one for full app, one for lite app).

Comment: When you're adding files to project you can define to which target it belongs (it can belong to all of them or just a few). For the files that are already in the project you can edit target membership by selecting view->utilities->file inspector

Comment: Aaaa... yes... I forgot. I've been using xCode for a while :).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **Preprocessor Macro** to the target of the lite version `LITE=1`. Then in your code, when you want to execute something differently you can use `#ifdef`, for example:

```
NSString *mainWindow;
#ifdef LITE
    mainWindow = @"MainWindow_Lite";
#else
    mainWindow = @"MainWindow_Full";
#endif
// Load nib with the name mainWindow.
// Or load ads in the lite version
// Or disable functionality in the lite version
//
```

If you want to avoid doing that and want to use the same name for the two nibs, you have to add one of them as a member of the full target and the other one as a member of the lite target.