# How is the right way to add images to a target

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I am trying to make a multibranded iOS-app. I have created a target for every brand. Now I want to add some images to the project. The images have the same name, but they have different content depending on brand.
I do ii like it is descripted in the accepted answer from this post:

[multiple-targets-multiple-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343860/xcode-4-multiple-targets-multiple-resources-folders-with-images-of-the-same-na)

I do this, but it doesn't work for me. The image wasn't found in any brand.
So I added every image manually to the `build resources` (target -> Build Phases). Now my images are shown correct in the app.

But in the Xcode-project every image is copied into the rootfolder.

[image]

If I use a lot of pictures, it is confusing. How is the right way to add images to a brand/target?

best regards

Comment: Hi. The simplest way is make a `xcassets` folder for the each brand-target. E.g. `images_brand1.xcassets`, `images_brand2.xcassets`. After that you should add the `assets` to the appropriate target. The images you should add to the `assets`, not to root folder.

Comment: This is the right way. Thanks for that.